# Reading 'Index Status' graph in Google Webmaster tools

Tags: google-search-console, google-index

I recently found a bunch of old files that had been ftp'ed to a live production server by mistake on a static (html / css / js) site.

I manually deleted these files, but today when checking in Google Webmaster tools i found this graph below. The 'update' marker is from 3/9/14, what i can work out is what Google is trying to tell me, are they saying that :

There was a ranking update like Penguin or Panda and they penalized my site and un-indexed a load of pages which they thought were junk..

**OR**

Is this showing that I updated the site by deleting the files on the server on 3/9/14

**OR**

Is this something else ?

[image: graph]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's trying to tell you something else -  The update is referring to an update within Webmaster tools its self, on how it now reports on indexed files. If you click the ['Learn More'](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2642366?hl=en)  it says:

> **Only data for your specific site**
>
> We do not show aggregate data for all versions of your site. While Google crawls and indexes content from
>   your site regardless of whether you have verified the site in
>   Webmaster Tools, the number of indexed URLs reported in Index status
>   are specific to those associated with your site version.
>
> For example, suppose you have a site with 10 URLs that people can view
>   without signing in, and 100 URLs that people can only see once they
>   sign into your site.  If you have added only one version of your site
>   to Webmaster Tools (e.g. http://www.example.com), you would see Index
>   status totals only for the non-secure portion of your site, which
>   would be a much lower number than for all URLs on your site.
>
> Therefore, in order to see the index count for your secure site, you
>   will need to add it to Webmaster Tools (e.g. https://www.example.com)
>   and then select it from the Site Selector.
>
> Similarly, you can verify a subdirectory of your site with Webmaster
>   Tools, and only data for that subdirectory will be shown in its Index
>   status (www.example.com/blog/).  However, the top-level domain will
>   continue to reflect the total count of URLs indexed for that domain.
>   We do not show aggregate data for all

So if you had subdomains or https versions of your site they all used to be reported under the same site in t Webmaster Tools account, however they wont be any more and you need too add them as  separate sites.